# Binomial coefficient proof

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Prove that for any $0\lt r\lt n$ we have $$\binom nr=\binom{n-1}{r-1}+\binom{n-1}r.$$

How do prove this and what step do i take in order for it to be true?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_rule

Comment: Have you tried using the definition of the binomial coefficient?

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Pascal's_Rule

Comment: Is this homework? If so, it matters what facts have previously been established in the class and it may matter what proof techniques you've recently been shown. For example, if this is an exercise following an explanation of mathematical induction, you may be expected to use induction.

Comment: How did you define $\binom{n}{r}$?

Comment: I deleted some comments after a merger.

Answer (score 6):

Ooh, one of those binomial coefficient questions that can be answered by giving a small story. I like those.

The concept to think about in this case is that of a bowl filled with $n$ balls and one of those $n$ balls is coloured pink, while the rest ($n-1$ in total) is just plain, boring white. If you take $r$ balls from this bowl, either the pink ball is one of those (in $\binom{n-1}{r-1}$ cases; can you see why?) or it isn't (in $\binom{n-1}{r}$ cases).

Answer (score 2):

This is simple. $(_r^n)$ corresponds to the number in the $(r+1)$th position of the $(n+1)$th row of pascal's triangle. Pascal's triangle is generated by, for each position, adding the numbers in the positions above it, which happen to be $(_{r-1}^{n-1})$ and $(_r^{n-1})$.

Comment: (Hint: You can use \binom{n}{k} for binomial coefficients in LaTeX)

Comment: @HSN Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, the inomial coefficient  $n\choose k$ is the coeffient of $x^k$ in the expansion of the binomial $(1+x)^n$.
From $$(1+x)^n=(1+x)^{n-1}\cdot (1+x)=(1+x)^{n-1} + x\cdot(1+x)^{n-1}$$
(for $n\ge 1$) we see that the coefficient of $x^r$ in $(1+x)^r$ is the sum of the coefficients of $x^{r}$ and of $x^{r-1}$ in $(1+x)^{n-1}$, in other words
$$ {n\choose r}={n-1\choose r}+{n-1\choose r-1}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a group of $n-1$ boys. You want to select $r-1$ or $r$ boys out of them.

You are too lazy to write $$\binom{n-1}{r-1}+\binom{n-1}{r}$$

So, you take Justin Bieber and put him with the $n-1$ boys and then select $r$ people.

$$\binom{n}{r}$$
If Justin Bieber comes up in your list, you can claim that he is not a guy you selected $r-1$ boys. If he doesn't, well, you selected $r$ boys.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the definition to $\binom{n-1}{r}+\binom{n-1}{r-1}$:

\begin{align*}
\frac{(n-1)!}{r!(n-1-r)!}+\frac{(n-1)!}{(r-1)!(n-1-(r-1))!}&=\\[1.5ex]
\frac{(n-1)!}{r!(n-1-r)!} \cdot \frac{n-r}{n-r}+\frac{(n-1)!}{(r-1)!(n-r)!} \cdot \frac{r}{r}&=\\[1.5ex]
\frac{(n-r)(n-1)!}{r!(n-r)!}+\frac{r(n-1)!}{r!(n-r)!}&=\\[1.5ex]
\frac{(n-r)(n-1)!+r(n-1)!}{r!(n-r)!}&=\\[1.5ex]
\frac{(n-1)!(n-r+r)}{r!(n-r)!}&=\\[1.5ex]
\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}. 
\end{align*}

Which is $\binom{n}{r}$ by definition.

Comment: You copy/pasted this same answer to two places. This is not ok. I deleted the other version.

Answer (score 0):

You have made no mistake. You are just failing to see how this equals $\binom{n}{r}$.

Notice that every factor of $N_2$ is also a factor of $N_1$. And there is only one factor of $N_1$, that is not a factor of $N_2$, which is $(n-r)$.

You can write $N_1 = N_2 \times (n-r)$

Then, $\dfrac{N_1 + r\cdot N_2}{r!} = \dfrac{N_2 \times (n-r) + r\cdot N_2}{r!} = \dfrac{N_2 \times ((n-r)+r)}{r!} = \dfrac{N_2 \times n}{r!}$.

Now substitute for $N_2$ to see it equals $\binom{n}{r}$.

Answer (score 0):

You have $n$ objects and you like to choose $r$ objects out of them.

Put one of them aside and choose your $r$ objects out of the remaining $n-1$ objects.

That gives you $$\binom {n-1}{r}$$ choices.

Now put the object back into  the pile and choose that object and $r-1$ objects from the remaining $n-1$ objects, that gives you  $$\binom {n-1}{r-1}$$ choices.

That takes care of all your choices.

Thus $$\binom  {n}{r} =  \binom {n-1}{r} +\binom {n-1}{r-1}$$