How to calculate ${n\choose k}+{n\choose{k+1}}$?
I am trying to calculate $n\choose k$ $+$ $n\choose k+1$. I had no idea on how to approach the calculation so I just tried to brute force it. I know that this is not the best idea, but I already put a lot of thought into this and wasn't able to find a nice easy way.
WolframAlpha said that I should come to $n+1\choose k+1$. But I first tried to ignore that, because in an exam I should be able to come to the right solution even without knowing the answer. So I tried the following:
\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{k} + \binom{n}{k+1} &= \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} + \frac{n!}{(k+1)!(n-(k+1))!} \\
&= \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} + \frac{n!}{(k+1)!(n-k-1)!} \\
&= \frac{n!(k+1)!(n-k-1)!}{k!(n-k)!(k+1)!(n-k-1)!} + \frac{n! k! (n-k)!}{k!(n-k)!(k+1)!(n-k-1)!} \\
&= \frac{n! (k+1)! (n-k-1)! + n! k! (n-k)!}{k!(n-k)!(k+1)!(n-k-1)!} \\
&= \frac{n!k!(k+1)(n-k-1)!+n!k!(n-k)!}{k!(n-k)!(k+1)!(n-k-1)!}\\
&= \frac{n!(k+1)(n-k-1)! + n!(n-k)!}{(n-k)!(k+1)!(n-k-1)!} \\
&= \frac{n!(k+1)(n-k-1)! + n!(n-k-1)!(n-k)}{(n-k)!(k+1)!(n-k-1)!} \\
&= \frac{n!(k+1) + n!(n-k)}{(n-k)! (k+1)!}
\end{align*}
But here I couldn't continue anymore. I would be happy if anyone could explain how I could get to the answer in the brute force way I tried above. And then if someone could also explain the easy way (because I assume that there exist some sort of trick which can be used).

This question here is quite similar and I think with using this identity I would be somehow able to solve the task. But I also went through my study material from my teacher and this identity was never shown or explained, so I assumed that I should be able to solve this task without this identity. So I still would be happy if someone could explain what went wrong in my brute force try, even though It is harder work, but I assume that it somehow has to be possible this way. Of course I will take a more in depth view at the identity as well. But I think my teacher wanted us to work with the binomials the way I tried with the brute force attempt.
The suggested duplicate wouldn't have helped me to solve my problem because with the answers there I wouldn't have came to the idea to factor out the $n!$. I also see that there is talked in a answer about factoring out but sadly I didn't understand the approach there.

Hi there! As you might guess this fundamental identity for binomial coefficients has already appeared a couple of times here on math.SE. For this reason I will vote to close. Meanwhile, you can check out the answers here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/807763/binomial-coefficient-proof. By the way, I found this by using the search feature of the website for about one minute.

How does this related to [tag:gcd-and-lcm]?

@MartinBrandenburg Thank you, very much. I am indeed able to use the search function and came across this question and many others, but all included a minus and somehow I am unable to transfer the answers there to my problem. One of the reasons is that many people try to argument with the properties of the binomial coefficient. But I also want to be able to understand what went wrong in my brute force attempt.

@user1176409 I thought because I had difficulties with finding a common denominator and with finding one I could be able to solve the brute force way more efficient.

There is nothing wrong with your approach, you just factor out $n!$, cancel the $k$, done. Notice that this calculation is also done in the linked question (just scroll down).

@DietrichBurde I tried to explain again with a second edit why the suggested duplicate isn't answering my question. I hope this satisfies you and if you have different concerns then please let me know!


I would be happy if anyone could explain how I could get to the answer in the brute force way I tried above.

There’s nothing wrong with your brute force, you can continue:
$$\frac{n!(k+1)+n!(n-k)}{(n-k)!(k+1)!}$$
$$=\frac{n!(k+1+n-k)}{(n-k)!(k+1)!}$$
$$=\frac{n!(n+1)}{(n-k)!(k+1)!}$$
$$=\frac{(n+1)!}{(n-k)!(k+1)!}$$
$$=\binom{n+1}{k+1}$$

Please don't post answers to duplicate questions.

I didn't see that I could factor out the $n!$, sometimes you just get blind. Thanks a lot!
